# How to mock Prisms IContainerRegistry

Tags: wpf, ninject, prism, prism-7

- Prism.Ninject 7.1.0.431
- Prism 7.1.0.431
- NUnit 3.3.3
- NSubstitute

Previously using Prism 6.3 we had a set of unit test to confirm that we had all of our bindings in place as follows

```
protected IKernel TestKernel;

[SetUp]
public void Given
{
    TestKernel = new StandardKernel();
    SUT = new MyModule( TestKernel );

    Core = Assembly.Load( "MyDLL.Core" ).GetTypes();
    Common = Assembly.Load( "MyDLL.Common" ).GetTypes();

    SUT.Initialize();
}

[ Test ]
public void Then_ViewModels_Will_Be_Bound()
{
    var testCollection = Common
        .Where( item => item.IsPublic )
        .Where( item => item.Name.EndsWith( "ViewModel" ) );

    foreach ( var item in testCollection )
    {
        Assert.That( TestKernel.GetBindings( item ).Any, $"Test Failed:  {item.Name}" );
    }
}
```

However in Ninject 7.1, the IModule interface has changed somewhat, so now parts are registered differently in

```
public void RegisterTypes(
        IContainerRegistry containerRegistry )
```

I'm just trying to get my unit tests up and running again with this new IModule format.  I had tried changing my given to be as follows

```
protected override void Given()
{
    TestKernel = new StandardKernel();

    TestContainerRegistry = Substitute.For<IContainerRegistry>();
    TestContainerRegistry.GetContainer().Returns( TestKernel );

    SUT = new MyModule();
}
```

However I get the following when I attempt to run my tests.

System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IContainerRegistryProxy' to type 'Prism.Ioc.IContainerExtension`1[Ninject.IKernel]'.

If anyone has any idea how I might be able to mock this it would be appreciated, as I'm currently at an impasse.

Comment: Why can't you use the real implementation? You don't write tests for other components of Prism, do you? So you trust them to function correctly, like you trust NSubstitute, and they should be fine to use in tests. Especially in this case where we're talking about a thin wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you should test is always a hot topic full of disagreement, so I will try to give you some general information here. Prism.Ninject implements the container abstractions with the `Prism.Ninject.Ioc.NinjectContainerExtension`. This has two constructors, a default and one that allows you to pass in a specific Kernel.

Prism also implements extension methods for each of the containers to pull the container from the abstraction. You can achieve this in a couple of ways:

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().SomeContainerSpecificApi()
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
var app = new MyApp();
app.Container.GetContainer().SomeContainerSpecificApi();
```

Again there are a variety of ways that you could implement your tests and I'm not about to get into how you should test. I will however say that in the event you don't want to create an app and you're just looking to validate that your types are registered for a Prism Module you might try something like:

```
var containerExtension = new NinjectContainerExtension();
var module = new MyModule();
module.RegisterTypes(containerExtension);
Assert.IsTrue(containerExtension.Instance.IsRegistered<MyType>());
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  I used containerExtension.Instance.GetBindings instead, but the result was much the same.

And if you do have any legitimate objection to how this test is done, please let me know (so long as it's not the usual "you're wrong I'm right" or "That's stupid" I often see in lieu of answers here) if there's a better way of doing something, I'd rather know.

Comment: Personally I'm not overly familiar with the Ninject API. I would say it sounds to me like you've achieved the goal of your unit tests with the GetBindings which is all that's really important IMO. The only thing I would tell you to consider is that you will get better performance from DryIoc… it is hands down the fastest performing Container we ship.

Comment: Oh I agree, we only started doing DI a few years ago after some contractors introduced it, and at the time Ninject was the one they were most familiar with, so it's what we adopted.  We have looked at switching in the past, but we've got a decent sized codebase that'd need to be transfered over.

At least with the new format in Prism it might make that transfer easier some day.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out (or made progress at least)

Instead of substituting with IContainerRegistry I had to use the following

```
protected override void Given()
{
    TestKernel = new StandardKernel();

    TestContainerRegistry = Substitute.For<IContainerExtension<IKernel>>();
    TestContainerRegistry.GetContainer().Returns( TestKernel );

    SUT = new MyModule();
}
```

Although it looks like I'm going to have to make more substitutes etc in order to have the containerRegistry.Register (etc) wind up in my TestKernel for verification.